# How to configure activemq to use informix database?

Tags: jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, informix

I am using apache activemq 5.8. Here is what i did:

1) put informix jdbc jar (ifxjdbc-3.70-JC3.jar) into activemq/libs/optional

2) declare bean in activemq.xml:

```
 <bean id="informix-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.7.30:21893/activemq_nightly:informixserver=ol_informix1170_1;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=20;IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED"/>
    <property name="username" value="XXXX" />
    <property name="password" value="XXXX" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="200" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

3) change persistence adapter in activemq.xml:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
    <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#informix-ds"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
```

I set Isolation level in the informix connection string because i was getting "transaction not supported" error while starting activemq.
Now i get this exceptions:

```
2013-04-12 14:21:23,196 | ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ (localhost, null). Reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Transaction not available.) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
```

java.io.IOException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Transaction not available.)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.getConnection(TransactionContext.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.loadAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:440)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.createAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.getAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.init(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:289)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.LockableServiceSupport.preStart(LockableServiceSupport.java:79)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartPersistenceAdapter(BrokerService.java:623)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startPersistenceAdapter(BrokerService.java:612)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:577)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Transaction not available.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.getConnection(TransactionContext.java:58)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction not available.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3550)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3871)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2662)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2578)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.c(IfxSqli.java:1512)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeExecute(IfxSqli.java:2493)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeExecute(IfxSqli.java:2430)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.b(IfxResultSet.java:393)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.a(IfxStatement.java:1326)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeImpl(IfxStatement.java:1296)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.c(IfxStatement.java:1007)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.execute(IfxStatement.java:893)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setServerIsolationLevel(IfxSqliConnect.java:6976)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.j(IfxSqliConnect.java:6947)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.(IfxSqliConnect.java:1766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.connect(IfxDriver.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3876)

When i start activemq i get the following error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Download latest activemq version

2) vi ACTIVEMQ_HOME/conf/activemq.xml

3) Add the following bean configuration to configure informix ds:

```
<bean id="informix-ds" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClass" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"/>
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.7.30:21893/XXX:informixserver=ol_informix1170_1;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=20;IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED"/>
<property name="user" value="XXXXX" />
<property name="password" value="XXXX" />
```

Note: Informix connection string should contain: IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED. Data Source implementation should be com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource

4) Register ds as persistence adapter:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
```

-->
        
        
5) Download and copy c3p0-0.8.4.5.jar and ifxjdbc-3.70-JC3.jar to ACTIVEMQ_HOME/lib/optional

6) Start activemq and enjoy!

NOTE: If activemq complains about missing db tables, check if your database is with single-byte character set or manually create the missing table with appropriate constraints (only for dev env).

Answer (score 0):

A good guess is what's described in the [informix help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.em.doc/errors_ids100.html)

> -122  ISAM error: transaction not available.
>
> The ISAM processor has been asked to mark the start or end of a
>   transaction, but transaction logging is not in effect. For C-ISAM
>   programs, this file was not opened with logging. Review the calls to
>   isopen, and make sure that the ISTRANS parameter is included. For SQL
>   products, this database does not support transaction logging. If you
>   are using the database server, have the database server administrator
>   enable logging for this database. Otherwise, use the START DATABASE
>   statement to begin transaction logging. In all cases, logging should
>   only start immediately after the database has been fully backed up.

Comment: I created new database with logging, but now i'm getting other exception:

Comment: Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource@1f38fc6) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2013-04-15 14:41:33,108 | WARN  | Could not get JDBC connection: java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)